# Django registration templates

Tags: django, templates, registration

I have downloaded [here](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/) some templates for django-registration.

Can somebody explain to me how resetting the password works ?

In password_reset_confirm.html, I don't understand where the `validlink` comes from :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if validlink %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% else %}
<p>Password reset failed.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In password_reset_email.html, I don't understand where that block called "reset_link" comes from, because we are not extending any template :

```
Reset password at {{ site_name }}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url auth_password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Furthermore shouldn't it be site.name ?

Answer (score 5):

`validlink` is initialised in Django's [password_reset_confirm](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L212) view:

The `reset_link` block from is [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html) so that you can extend this template from your project.

The views for `password_reset_confirm` and `password_reset_email` will be run from Django source.  For example, `password_reset_confirm` view will render template:

```
template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'
```

Assuming you have `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` in the following order in your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

By placing the customised `password_reset_confirm.html` in your project at:

```
yourproject/
    templates/
        registration/
            password_reset_confirm.html
```

Django's template loader searches for `password_reset_confirm.html` in your project's `templates` folder first and then in Django's own registration app if the previous search is unsuccessful.

You can read more about [Django's template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#loader-types).

Answer (score 1):

Every django app you download from pypi is stored in your (in case of virtualenv)envname/lib/site-packages/app-installed. As you define urls in your app on local server you developed yourself same like that apps are stored with urls in site-packages. In case you need to see a ref for the app url you can look into relevant urls.py. In your case you can go to registration and see for url name assigned to it. Your input should be something like `"<input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="{% trans 'Reset' %}" />"` below the form. {% trans 'Reset' %} will take you to the exact url.